# How to add additional columns with a Left Join without losing values in columns from right table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Table A**
Country | Date | Source | Campaign | Leads (sum)

**Table B**
Country | Date | Source | Campaign | Purchases (sum) | Revenue (sum)

```
SELECT
a.*,
b.purchases,
b.revenue

FROM
Table A 
LEFT JOIN 
Table B 

ON a.country = b.country and a.date = b.date and a.source = b.source and a.campaign = b.campaign
```

**Desired Output:**

Country | Date | Source | Campaign | Leads | Purchases | Revenue

When I do this, the total number of leads remain the same as in Table A but the total number of purchases and sum of revenue from Table B drops after the join. This should not be the case.

I'm not able to figure out why this would be the case - the idea is that not all campaign leads result in a purchase, hence the Left Join instead of Inner Join.

**Update:**

Table A

```
country times   sources camp    leads
Germany 01-Jan-20   Facebook    a   227
Germany 02-Jan-20   Facebook    b   175
Germany 03-Jan-20   Facebook    c   215
Germany 04-Jan-20   Facebook        23
Germany 05-Jan-20   Facebook        251
Germany 06-Jan-20   Facebook    d   135
Germany 07-Jan-20   Facebook        257
Germany 08-Jan-20   Facebook    e   54
Germany 09-Jan-20   Facebook        51
Germany 10-Jan-20   Facebook        27
Germany 11-Jan-20   Facebook        264
Germany 12-Jan-20   Facebook    f   41
Germany 13-Jan-20   Facebook        359
Germany 14-Jan-20   Facebook        2
Germany 15-Jan-20   Facebook    g   33
```

Table B

```
country times   sources camp    purchases   revenue
Germany 01-Jan-20   Facebook    a       
Germany 02-Jan-20   Facebook    b       
Germany 03-Jan-20   Facebook    c   1   127.88
Germany 04-Jan-20   Facebook        1   93.42
Germany 05-Jan-20   Facebook        1   74.18
Germany 06-Jan-20   Facebook    d       
Germany 07-Jan-20   Facebook            
Germany 08-Jan-20   Facebook    e       
Germany 09-Jan-20   Facebook            
Germany 10-Jan-20   Facebook        1   85.36
Germany 11-Jan-20   Facebook        1   79.77
Germany 12-Jan-20   Facebook    f   1   121.01
Germany 13-Jan-20   Facebook            
Germany 14-Jan-20   Facebook            
Germany 15-Jan-20   Facebook    g   1
```

[image: Output data with outer or full joins]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be your expectation is to get the sum of Leads, Purchases and Revenue. Please use below query,

```
SELECT
a.Country,    a.Date,    a.Source,    a.Campaign,    sum(a.Leads)    sum(b.purchases),    sum(b.revenue)
FROM
 Table A 
 LEFT JOIN 
 Table B 
ON a.country = b.country and a.date = b.date and a.source = b.source and a.campaign = 
b.campaign;
```

If this is not what you are expecting, please provide sample data and your expected result. Would be more helpful to provide you the solution

Comment: Hey Jim, I've tried this too but the SUM function gave the same results.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use full outer join if you need to get all the data from both tables:

```
SELECT
ifnull(a.country,b.country) country,
ifnull(a.date,b.date) date,
ifnull(a.source,b.source) source,
ifnull(a.campaign,b.campaign) campaign,
a.leads,
b.purchases,
b.revenue

FROM
Table A 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
Table B 

ON a.country = b.country and a.date = b.date and a.source = b.source and a.campaign = b.campaign
```

if I misunderstood you question, please provide a sample data

**update:**

try this:

```
WITH
  table_a AS (
  SELECT
    'A' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'X' Source,
    'L' Campaign,
    100 Leads
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'X' Source,
    'L' Campaign,
    200 Leads
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'Y' Source,
    'M' Campaign,
    300 Leads
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'Y' Source,
    'M' Campaign,
    400 Leads ),
  table_b AS (
  SELECT
    'A' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'X' Source,
    'L' Campaign,
    100 Purchases,
    100000 revenue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'X' Source,
    'L' Campaign,
    200 Purchases,
    30000
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'Y' Source,
    'M' Campaign,
    400 Purchases,
    40000
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'C' Country,
    '2020-01-01' Date,
    'X' Source,
    'L' Campaign,
    200 Purchases,
    30000)
SELECT
  ifnull(a.country,
    b.country) country,
  ifnull(a.date,
    b.date) date,
  ifnull(a.source,
    b.source) source,
  ifnull(a.campaign,
    b.campaign) campaign,
  a.leads,
  b.purchases,
  b.revenue
FROM
  table_a a
FULL OUTER JOIN
  table_b b
ON
  a.country = b.country
  AND a.date = b.date
  AND a.source = b.source
  AND a.campaign = b.campaign
```

Comment: Hi Joe this worked! Full Outer Join should be used instead of Left Join.

Comment: Hi Joe, when `ifnull` is used i get an error for - "No matching signature for function".

Without `ifnull`, the final sums matched (if i sum the columns in the output) but the purchase and revenue data do not get correctly mapped when one of the columns (e.g. campaign) is null. I suppose this is due to the absence of `ifnull`?

Comment: you shouldn't get this error , you're combining two different datatypes in ifnull, so ifnull(a,b) a and b should be in the same datatype, check the example i used

Comment: Updated with sample data - sorry about the formatting. So where I think it goes wrong is when the tables try to join on campaign data but have null values for campaign in some rows? As a result the output of the full outer join gives rows with null data in all columns except for purchases or revenue.

Would it be better to replace all null campaign column with a string like "unmatched"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `join` conditions do not product duplicates, I would suggest using `full join` with `using`:

```
SELECT country, date, source, campaign,
       COALESCE(a.leads, 0) as leads,
       COALESCE(b.purchases, 0) as purchases,
       COALESCE(b.revenue, 0) as revenue
FROM TableA a FULL JOIN
     TableB b
     USING (country, date, source, campaign);
```

This will keep all rows in both tables.  The `USING` clause makes it easy to avoid `NULL` values on the key columns used in the `JOIN`.  The `COALESCE()` is because I'm guessing you really want `0` values for the rows that are in only one table -- but you can remove it if you are happy with `NULL`.